# Best and worst case runtime inputs for a function

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

```
function Find(key,B,M,j)
    for 0 <= i < M
        if(B[i] == key):
            return j + 2*i
    return -1
```

`
B is one of the arrays (A1 or A2), its length M and non negative integer j as inputs

`

```
function R0(key,A1,A2,N)
    index = Find(key,A1,ceiling(N/2),0)
    if (index == -1):
        return Find(key,A2,floor(N/2),1)
    return index
```

`If A1 = [7, 6, 2, 4 ,9] and A2 = [5, 3, 1, 8]. what is the best and worst case inputs for running time? key is value that looking for, N is the length of array and Recall that there are four inputs to R0.`

Comment: Best and worst by what measure? Value of the output? Performance? Memory usage? Something else? How is this recursive? What does the `Find` function do and what do its parameters mean? This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: @Welbog I have edited my code .

Comment: So then your goal is to have as few and as many iterations inside of `Find`'s loop as possible. What inputs do you think minimize and maximize the number of times that loop iterates? Where are you stuck with your attempts to find the answer?

Comment: @ Welbog I am not sure that this is correct, best case inputs for R0 is sorted array A1 and A2 , and The worst case input is not sorted arrays. I am looking for inputs.

Comment: It sounded like from the problem description that `A1` and `A2` are fixed, and only `key` and `N` are things you can choose? If not, why not just make `A1` and `A2` as short and long as possible?

Comment: @Welbog the logic is to start with an array A of
length N storing non-negative integers, and create two new arrays (A1, A2) where the first array stores
the values A[i] where i is an even number, and the second array stores the values A[j]
where j is an odd number.  two new arrays, A1 and A2, are created and the values at even numbered indices of A are copied to A1, and the values at odd-numbered indices are copied to
A2.

Comment: It sounds like there's a lot more context to this problem that you haven't included in your question. Can you please provide all details that matter to the problem (what the inputs are, what you're allowed to modify and not modify). What is the purpose of your question? It looks like homework. Is this for something else? If so, what?